# How to use foreach in this Case

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

Can you help me with this problem?

Im using C# and after getting data from the repository, I have to show the results according to a rule.

I used a distinct for an specific column called Level, and the results are the next ones:

```
foreach (var lev in Model.Commissions.Select(x => x.Level).Distinct()
```

And it prints:

```
"1P, "9C", "1T", "6C", "7B", "5C", "4C", "2T"
```

(It can be more or less distinct records depends on the selection of the query)

How Can I use a foreach for that column with distinct applied to get the output in this order?

```
"5C", "1P", "1T", "2T", "4C", "6C", "7B", "9C".
```

*The rule is that 5C is always first and after that the rest in order asc*, but I don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: Just add `.OrderBy(lev => lev != "5C").ThenBy(lev => lev)` after the `Distinct`.

Answer (score -1):

First parse the "5C" from the list and than search everything else in your list as you would do but exclude "5C" from your second list.

Last step would be to conact both lists together to get all elements of the list.

```
var fiveC = Model.Commissions.Where(x => x.Level == "5C").ToList();
var rest = Model.Commissions.Where(x => x.Level != "5C").OrderBy(x => x.Level).ToList();

var result = fiveC.Concat(rest).ToList();
```

At the end you can do your foreach in a distinct order:

```
foreach (var lev in result.Select(x => x.Level).Distinct())
{
//Do here whatever you need to do
}
```